# system/ajax 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: 7

It's been almost 2 days I've been trying to get over this issue but I can't. So I have a content type and in Manage Display section I have a "rendered view" field using node reference, [Display Suit](https://drupal.org/project/ds) and [Node Reference View Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/node_reference_view_formatter) modules. I tried the module side by updating to the latest version (tried dev also) but it's not it.

anyway everything was working just fine but after a while I wanted to change some configuration in display of my content type, and when I click the edit button the Ajax thing cant be loaded and I get 502 bad gateway system/ajax error.

I checked nginx server logs and I got this:

> recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response
>   header from upstream, server: news.example.com, request: "POST
>   /system/ajax HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
>   "tools.example.com", referrer:
>   "http://tools.example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display"

I'm running a nginx server with drupal 7, I already tried increasing php memory_limit, maximum_post_size, fastcgi_buffers & fastcgi_buffer_size, and didn't helped at all.

I'm not sure if it's a server issue or drupal-related, I have no Idea how to debug this, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: *Connection reset by peer* - have you asked your peer why does he resets connection? Without that knowledge, we are blind and can only guess. Also, could you use [proper substitution domains](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186529/help-users-create-dummy-links-that-are-not-to-unrelated-commercial-sites)? Now it looks like there are 2 involved, but maybe you just missed one substitution, so maybe make it example.org for your site and example.com for the other one (if any)?

Comment: you need to ask admin of the network which computer is the "peer" in that message, and then examine it's logs. Or ask it's owner to do it. Detailed explanations will be easier to find on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), if it's a professional server room.